# handlebars conditional block

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Apologies for such a immature question.

I'm very new to handlebars and not sure what approach to take here.

I have this JSON:

```
{
"fieldName": "amount",
"locked": false,
"visible": true,
"visibilityCheckBox": "UNCHECKED",
"values": [],
"domain": null
},
{
"fieldName": "awardType",
"locked": false,
"visible": true,
"visibilityCheckBox": "UNCHECKED",
"values": [],
"domain": null
},
{
"fieldName": "currencyCode",
"locked": false,
"visible": true,
"visibilityCheckBox": "UNCHECKED",
"values": [],
"domain": null
}
```

I want to populate following HTML from JSON using handlebars:

```
<input id="timeUnspecified" type="text" name="awardType" value="from JSON"/>
```

How can I compare name with key in JSON using handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

**Handlebars Template** (Tipically used like a .hbs file or a string variable):

```
{{#if myValue}}value="{{myValue}}"{{/if}}
```

**Javascript**:

```
//Where template is your handlebars template
var myTemp = Handlebars.compile(template);
//This console.log will print value="hi"
console.log(myTemp({
    myValue: "hi"
}));
```

The previous code will write `myValue` only if exists or contains a falsy value (`""`, `0`, `false`);

You have a JSFiddle with your specific example: http://jsfiddle.net/vy2qK/

Comment: What is myValue? How do I find/match appropriate field name? Could you please give me complete example?

Comment: The variable whatever you want, whatever you have passed to Handlebars.

Comment: You have a more complete example.

Comment: It's a simpler case. Instead of using {my Value} , you can use your array using `{{#each variable}}[CODE]{{/each}}` , where variable is your JSON.

Comment: +1 for your efforts but I'm not able to see how it'll work in my case. I'll accept the answer if you can give me working example on fiddle?

Comment: Almost there, I have a problem I can't render template using handlebars, I just need to populate the value. The template has been rendered on backend?

Comment: No, the Handlebars template in the example is pure client side, although you could use Handlebars in the server side too with nodeJS.

Comment: I understand but we are refactoring really old code here. Is there any way to put that value to pre- rendered form?

Comment: Using a variable:

`var template = "{{#if value}}value='{{value}}'{{/value}}";`

`...`

`//use as usual`